# What is the default zoom level for Internet Explorer?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

I'm guessing it's going to / might be different for each browser, but for IE 8 and IE 10, does anyone know the default zoom level it is set to when you first install / use the browser?

Comment: You can hit `Ctrl+0` to make sure that you are at the default zoom level (`100%`) in any of the major browsers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100% - If you're noticing a marked difference between a site rendered in each browser, it'll be because IE8 doesn't work well with modern web standards whereas IE10 is much more compliant.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#HTML5_support